# installer setup project fails at installation

Tags: windows-installer, installation, windows-xp

I have created a setup project using Visual Studio 2013. When installing on windows xp, I get the following error:

The installer was interrupted before [Application] could be installed. You need to restart the installer to try again.

How do I fix this problem?

The log file shows the following.

```
=== Verbose logging started: 10/03/2015  16.58.11  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 4.05.6001.00  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:758]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:758]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:758]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: c:\stp\agencyManagerSetup.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:758]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:788]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'c:\stp\agencyManagerSetup.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:788]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:788]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: c:\stp\agencyManagerSetup.msi is not digitally signed
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:788]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: c:\stp\agencyManagerSetup.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:808]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:808]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:828]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:828]: Original package ==> c:\stp\agencyManagerSetup.msi
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:828]: Package we're running from ==> c:\DOCUME~1\teo\IMPOST~1\Temp\374676.msi
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{A35CD080-949F-490D-A5A9-1297B9652D80}'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiFileHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Enabling baseline caching for this transaction since all active patches are MSI 3.0 style MSPs or at least one MSI 3.0 minor update patch is active
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{A35CD080-949F-490D-A5A9-1297B9652D80}'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'c:\mylogtemp.log'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Command Line: CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Documents and Settings\teo CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=872 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{A130C114-D814-4400-AF9E-F44BD5A3856A}'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           ''
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{A35CD080-949F-490D-A5A9-1297B9652D80}'
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{A35CD080-949F-490D-A5A9-1297B9652D80}'
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Package name extracted from package path: 'agencyManagerSetup.msi'
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:838]: Package to be registered: 'agencyManagerSetup.msi'
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: Running product '{A35CD080-949F-490D-A5A9-1297B9652D80}' with user privileges: It's not assigned.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\Documents and Settings\teo'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '872'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Dati applicazioni
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Preferiti
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Risorse di rete
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Documenti
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Risorse di stampa
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Recent
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\SendTo
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Modelli
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Dati applicazioni
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Impostazioni locali\Dati applicazioni
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Documenti\Immagini
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Menu Avvio\Programmi\Strumenti di amministrazione
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Menu Avvio\Programmi\Esecuzione automatica
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Menu Avvio\Programmi
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Menu Avvio
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Desktop
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Menu Avvio\Programmi\Strumenti di amministrazione
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Menu Avvio\Programmi\Esecuzione automatica
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Menu Avvio\Programmi
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Menu Avvio
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'matteo'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'c:\DOCUME~1\teo\IMPOST~1\Temp\374676.msi'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'c:\stp\agencyManagerSetup.msi'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'c:\stp\'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:848]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'c:\stp\'.
MSI (c) (68:F8) [16:58:11:858]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionHandler property. Its value is '4.05'.
=== Inizio registrazione: 10/03/2015  16.58.11 ===
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:868]: Note: 1: 2262 2: PatchPackage 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:868]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:868]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:868]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '5'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:868]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:868]: Doing action: INSTALL
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:868]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ActionText 3: -2147287038 
Operazione 16.58.11: INSTALL. 
Inizio operazione 16.58.11: INSTALL.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:868]: UI Sequence table 'InstallUISequence' is present and populated.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:868]: Running UISequence
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:868]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:868]: Doing action: DIRCA_CheckFX
Operazione 16.58.11: DIRCA_CheckFX. 
Inizio operazione 16.58.11: DIRCA_CheckFX.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:878]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'DIRCA_CheckFX' 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:11:878]: Creating MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790542 for thread 408
MSI (c) (68:E8) [16:58:11:878]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\DOCUME~1\teo\IMPOST~1\Temp\MSI7.tmp, Entrypoint: CheckFX
MSI (c) (68:F0) [16:58:11:888]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (68:F0) [16:58:11:888]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (68:F0) [16:58:11:888]: Connected to service for CA interface.
MSI (c) (68:E8) [16:58:12:028]: Closing MSIHANDLE (1) of type 790542 for thread 408
Fine operazione 16.58.12: DIRCA_CheckFX. Valore restituito 3.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:12:028]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
Operazione 16.58.12: FatalErrorForm. 
Inizio operazione 16.58.12: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:12:028]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm' 
MSI (c) (68:F8) [16:58:12:038]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Informazioni 2898. For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (68:F8) [16:58:12:038]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
Si è verificato un errore imprevisto durante l'installazione di questo pacchetto. Probabile problema con questo pacchetto. Il codice errore è 2826. Gli argomenti sono: FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right
MSI (c) (68:F8) [16:58:12:038]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
Si è verificato un errore imprevisto durante l'installazione di questo pacchetto. Probabile problema con questo pacchetto. Il codice errore è 2826. Gli argomenti sono: FatalErrorForm, Line2, to the right
MSI (c) (68:F8) [16:58:12:038]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
Si è verificato un errore imprevisto durante l'installazione di questo pacchetto. Probabile problema con questo pacchetto. Il codice errore è 2826. Gli argomenti sono: FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right
MSI (c) (68:F8) [16:58:12:048]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Informazioni 2898. For VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
MSI (c) (68:F8) [16:58:12:048]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
Informazioni 2898. For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif16.0_1_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 20 pixels height.
Operazione 16.58.12: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created
Fine operazione 16.58.16: FatalErrorForm. Valore restituito 1.
Fine operazione 16.58.16: INSTALL. Valore restituito 3.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:16:224]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
MSI (c) (68:F0) [16:58:16:245]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
Property(C): UpgradeCode = {7EC60388-8DFC-4C3E-8435-A126EBCD2A0B}
Property(C): SourceDir = c:\stp\
Property(C): DesktopFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Desktop\
Property(C): AppDataFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Dati applicazioni\
Property(C): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Menu Avvio\Programmi\
Property(C): StartMenuFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Menu Avvio\
Property(C): VSDFrameworkVersion = v3.5
Property(C): VSDAllowLaterFrameworkVersions = False
Property(C): ProductName = agencyManagerSetup
Property(C): ProductCode = {A35CD080-949F-490D-A5A9-1297B9652D80}
Property(C): ProductVersion = 1.0.0
Property(C): Manufacturer = M&M
Property(C): ARPCONTACT = M&M
Property(C): ProductLanguage = 1040
Property(C): SecureCustomProperties = NEWERPRODUCTFOUND
Property(C): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(C): VersionNT = 501
Property(C): VSDNETURLMSG = L'installazione richiede .NET Framework versione [1].  Installare .NET Framework ed eseguire nuovamente l'installazione. È possibile ottenere .NET Framework dal Web. Eseguire il download ora?
Property(C): VSDIISMSG = Il programma di installazione richiede Internet Information Server 5.1 o versione successiva e Windows XP o versione successiva, mentre non può essere eseguito su Windows 2000. Installare Internet Information Server o un sistema operativo più recente ed eseguire di nuovo il programma di installazione.
Property(C): VSDUIANDADVERTISED = Questa applicazione annunciata non verrà installata perché potrebbe essere non affidabile. Rivolgersi all'amministratore di sistema per modificare l'opzione di installazione del package in quella di base.
Property(C): VSDNETMSG = Il programma di installazione richiede .NET Framework versione [1]. Installare .NET Framework ed eseguire di nuovo il programma di installazione.
Property(C): VSDINVALIDURLMSG = Il percorso specificato " [2] " non è disponibile. Internet Information Server potrebbe non essere in esecuzione oppure è possibile che il percorso esista e venga reindirizzato su un altro computer. Verificare lo stato di questa directory virtuale in Gestione servizi Internet.
Property(C): VSDVERSIONMSG = Impossibile eseguire l'installazione. La versione più recente del prodotto è già installata.
Property(C): ErrorDialog = ErrorDialog
Property(C): SFF_UpFldrBtn = UpFldrBtn
Property(C): SFF_NewFldrBtn = NewFldrBtn
Property(C): AdminMaintenanceForm_Action = Repair
Property(C): DefaultUIFont = VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400
Property(C): MaintenanceForm_Action = Repair
Property(C): FolderForm_AllUsers = ME
Property(C): FolderForm_AllUsersVisible = 1
Property(C): EulaForm_Property = No
Property(C): AdminEulaForm_Property = No
Property(C): WelcomeForm_NextArgs = EulaForm
Property(C): EulaForm_PrevArgs = WelcomeForm
Property(C): EulaForm_NextArgs = FolderForm
Property(C): FolderForm_PrevArgs = EulaForm
Property(C): FolderForm_NextArgs = ConfirmInstallForm
Property(C): ConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs = FolderForm
Property(C): AdminWelcomeForm_NextArgs = AdminEulaForm
Property(C): AdminEulaForm_PrevArgs = AdminWelcomeForm
Property(C): AdminEulaForm_NextArgs = AdminFolderForm
Property(C): AdminFolderForm_PrevArgs = AdminEulaForm
Property(C): AdminFolderForm_NextArgs = AdminConfirmInstallForm
Property(C): AdminConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs = AdminFolderForm
Property(C): MsiLogFileLocation = c:\mylogtemp.log
Property(C): PackageCode = {A130C114-D814-4400-AF9E-F44BD5A3856A}
Property(C): ProductState = -1
Property(C): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(C): CURRENTDIRECTORY = C:\Documents and Settings\teo
Property(C): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(C): CLIENTPROCESSID = 872
Property(C): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(C): VersionMsi = 4.05
Property(C): WindowsBuild = 2600
Property(C): ServicePackLevel = 3
Property(C): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(C): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(C): WindowsVolume = c:\
Property(C): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(C): System16Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system\
Property(C): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(C): TempFolder = C:\DOCUME~1\teo\IMPOST~1\Temp\
Property(C): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Programmi\
Property(C): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Programmi\File comuni\
Property(C): FavoritesFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Preferiti\
Property(C): NetHoodFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Risorse di rete\
Property(C): PersonalFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Documenti\
Property(C): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Risorse di stampa\
Property(C): RecentFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Recent\
Property(C): SendToFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\SendTo\
Property(C): TemplateFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Modelli\
Property(C): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Dati applicazioni\
Property(C): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Impostazioni locali\Dati applicazioni\
Property(C): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Documenti\Immagini\
Property(C): AdminToolsFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Menu Avvio\Programmi\Strumenti di amministrazione\
Property(C): StartupFolder = C:\Documents and Settings\teo\Menu Avvio\Programmi\Esecuzione automatica\
Property(C): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(C): GPTSupport = 1
Property(C): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): Intel = 6
Property(C): PhysicalMemory = 1024
Property(C): VirtualMemory = 2361
Property(C): AdminUser = 1
Property(C): LogonUser = teo
Property(C): UserSID = S-1-5-21-1220945662-492894223-1202660629-1003
Property(C): UserLanguageID = 1040
Property(C): ComputerName = MATTEO-4135832B
Property(C): SystemLanguageID = 1040
Property(C): ScreenX = 1024
Property(C): ScreenY = 768
Property(C): CaptionHeight = 26
Property(C): BorderTop = 1
Property(C): BorderSide = 1
Property(C): TextHeight = 16
Property(C): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(C): ColorBits = 32
Property(C): TTCSupport = 1
Property(C): Time = 16.58.16
Property(C): Date = 10/03/2015
Property(C): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 2.0.50727.3053
Property(C): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 5.1.2600.5512
Property(C): Privileged = 1
Property(C): USERNAME = matteo
Property(C): DATABASE = c:\DOCUME~1\teo\IMPOST~1\Temp\374676.msi
Property(C): OriginalDatabase = c:\stp\agencyManagerSetup.msi
Property(C): SOURCEDIR = c:\stp\
Property(C): VersionHandler = 4.05
Property(C): UILevel = 5
Property(C): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
=== Fine registrazione: 10/03/2015 16.58.16 ===
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:16:305]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:16:305]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:16:305]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:16:305]: Prodotto: agencyManagerSetup -- Installazione non riuscita.

MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:16:305]: Windows Installer: installazione del prodotto completata. Nome prodotto: agencyManagerSetup. Versione prodotto: 1.0.0. Lingua prodotto: 1040. Installazione riuscita o stato di errore: 1603.

MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:16:315]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:16:315]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (68:98) [16:58:16:315]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 10/03/2015  16.58.16 ===
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can't fix this. Windows XP support has ended, and so there is no reason for Visual Studio 2013 to generate setups that will work on XP.

The actual error is a failure in the custom action that VS generates to check for the .NET Runtime. I'd guess that there's something in the code that doesn't work on XP. You don't say which version of .NET is required for your setup, or whether you ran setup.exe to install it as a prerequisite first or not. It's possible that if the required .NET runtime is already installed then the checkfx custom action won't get far enough to fail.